# Undeclared Identifier with all the right includes

Tags: c++, undeclared-identifier

Everytime I try to build the program I get this error:

```
error C2065: 'DepositoFresco' : undeclared identifier
```

This happens with every instance I create of `DepositoFresco`, `DepositoNormal` and `Deposito`. `DepositoNormal` and `DepositoFresco` are subclasses of `Deposito` (virtual class). I have all the right includes so I don't know what's causing this.
The error occurs in the class 'Armazem' where I instantiate several of these to insert in vectors and such. Here's the code:

```
Armazem::Armazem(int nF, int nN, int nPF, int nPN, int distMaxi, int distMini) : depositos(), distancia(), graphStlPath <Deposito*, int>() {
distMax = distMaxi;
distMin = distMini;

for (int i = 0; i < nF; i++) {
    DepositoFresco* df = new DepositoFresco(random(1, 20), (float)random(1000, 10000), nPF);
    depositos[i] = df;
}

for (int j = nF; j < nF + nN; j++) {
    DepositoNormal* dn = new DepositoNormal(random(1, 20), (float)random(1000, 10000), nPN);
    depositos[j] = dn;
}

preencherMatriz();
}
```

Also, `Armazem` is a subclass to another template class called `GraphStlPath` but I don't think the problem is here.

EDIT: Here are the includes:`include "Deposito.h"
    include "DepositoFresco.h"
    include "DepositoNormal.h"
    include "graphStlPath.h"
    include <vector>
    include <map>
    include <stdlib.h>
    include <stdio.h>
    include <time.h>
    include <typeinfo>
    include <iostream>
    include <fstream>
    include <string>`

Any help finding the problem is really apreciated.

Comment: How do *we* know you have "all the right includes"? Can you please  create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: The includes are added now. I forgot them, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that you have a cycle in your includes, and header guards or `#pragma once` are kicking in, making code disappear for the compiler.

That, or you are not respecting namespaces. But the first one is more likely.

Comment: The problem wasn't in this class, I had an include for this class (for some reason) on one of the classes that this one includes, generating a cycle. Just answering to shed some light if anyone else sees this ever and doesn't understand why exactly.